# How can I create a custom fall off, for edit mode?

Tags: modeling

I need to create a custom fall of curve for proportional editing, how can I achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK you can't...or you write your own add-on for that.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet here would probably be to go into Sculpt mode and use the grab brush for which you can adjust the fallof. You won't have as much control over which vertex you want to grab but if your mesh isn't too dense it should be doable and if it is then you are better off using the sculpt tool for this kind of task anyway